# Возможно ли достать из EXE-шника исходный код?

Tags: python, декомпиляция

Как все же посмотреть а если нужно то корректировать исходник программы? Ну к примеру я написал на Python прогу которая выключает комп, таймер грубо говоря, и смогу ли я изменить исходник как-нибудь?

Comment: В EXE исходного кода тупо нет. И хорошо, если есть дебажная информация - иначе и имён нет. А поскольку один и тот же ЕХЕ может быть собран с использованием разных компиляторов и библиотек - дело труба, один и тот же код произведёт разные ЕХЕ (даже опции компиляции и линковки - и те влияют). *я написал на Python прогу ... смогу ли я изменить исходник как-нибудь?* Если и правда ТЫ написал - то у тебя есть исходник. Меняй.

Comment: То есть получается если я захочу модифицировать какую-нибудь программу, но при этом имея только EXE-шник на руках. У меня прикол не выйдет?

Comment: Верно. Скорее нет, чем да. Обычно проще состыковаться с разработчиком и попросить доработать/модифицировать программу (или даже выпросить исходный код).

Comment: @Artur Если ты хорошо знаешь ассемблер то можешь конечно изменить все что угодно в exe-файле. Ибо в exe-файле все уже представлено в командах процессора, которые однозначно выражаются только ассемблером.

Comment: С другой стороны, просто так exe из питоновских программ вообще не делается, потому как это интерпретируемый язык. И для точного ответа на вопрос надо изучать ту программу, с помощью которой изготавливается exe

Comment: потенциально вооружившись hex-редактором можно исправить какие-нибудь константы

Comment: Это зависит от того, как этот exe'шник делался. Если чем-нибудь вроде pyinstaller, то запросто https://toster.ru/q/505168

Comment: @teran , вооружившись hex-редактором можно исправить значение только так, чтобы оно не поменяло своего конечного размера. Есть в условной переменной находится 10 символов, то эти 10 символов должны и остаться, в ином случае будет просто краш программы. Эти 10 символов можно менять, но так, чтобы они остались в данных рамках.

Comment: @MoloF благодарю за консультацию. я в курсе.